# A Hartogs analogue?

Tags: cv.complex-variables, several-complex-variables

Let $0<r<1<R$, and $A:=\{z\in \ell^2: r<\|z\|_2<R\}$.

For $n\in \mathbb{N}$, let $e_n$ denote the sequence in $\ell^2$ all of whose terms are zero, except the $n^{\text{th}}$ term, which is $1$,
and let $A_n:=\{(z_1,\dots, z_n)\in \mathbb{C}^n: r^2<|z_1|^2+\dots+|z_n|^2<R^2\}$.

A function $f:A\to \mathbb{C}$ is *holomorphic* if $f$ is continuous, and for each $n\in \mathbb{N}$, the map $A_n\owns(z_1,\dots, z_n)\mapsto f(z_1e_1+\dots+z_ne_n)\in \mathbb{C}$ is holomorphic.

If $f:A\to \mathbb{C}$ is holomorphic, then does it have a holomorphic extension $F$ to  $\{z\in \ell^2: \|z\|_2<R\}$?